# How can I do bash arithmetic with variables that are numbers with leading zeroes?

Tags: bash, command-line, sh

I have the following code in a bash script, where "values" is a variable of newline separated numbers, **some of which have leading 0's**, and I am trying to iterate through each value in values and add each value to the variable "sum".

```
sum=0
while read line; do
    sum=$(( sum + line ))
done <<< "$values"
```

this code segment gives me the error: "value too great for base (error token is "09")", which as I understand, is because the bash arithmetic expression interprets the value "line" to be an octal value because it has a leading zero.

How can I allow for bash to interpret the value of line to be its decimal value? (e.g. 09 -> 9) for the value "line" within this bash arithmetic expression?

Comment: @Rafael, ...why does that strike you as meaning the assumption is wrong? `02` is still 2, and `3` is decimal because it doesn't have any leading zero. Hence, you get `5` whether the `02` is octal *or* decimal.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy :facepalm: I can't believe I missed that

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You can override the "leading 0 means octal" by explicitly forcing base ten with `10#`:

```
sum=$(( 10#$sum + 10#$line ))
```

Note that, while you can usually leave the `$` off variable references in arithmetic contexts, in this case you need it. Also, if the variable has leading spaces (in front of the first "0"), it won't parse correctly.

Answer (score 2):

To trim a single leading zero:

```
"${line#0}"
```

To trim any number of leading zeros:

```
"${line##+(0)}"
```

For example:

```
$ line=009900
$ echo "${line##+(0)}"
9900
```

Answer (score 0):

You can just get *rid* of the leading zeros, with something like:

```
shopt extglob on
x="${x##+(0)}"
[[ -z "${x}" ]] && x=0
```

This will remove all leading zeros and then catch the case where it was *all* zeros (leading to an empty string), restoring it to a single zero.

The following function (and test code) will show this in action:

```
#!/bin/bash

stripLeadingZeros() {
    shopt -s extglob
    retVal="${1##+(0)}"
    [[ -z "${retVal}" ]] && retVal=0
    echo -n "${retVal}"
}

for testdata in 1 2 3 4 5 0 09 009 00000009 hello 00hello ; do
    result="$(stripLeadingZeros ${testdata})"
    echo "${testdata} -> ${result}"
done
```

The output of that is:

```
1 -> 1
2 -> 2
3 -> 3
4 -> 4
5 -> 5
0 -> 0
09 -> 9
009 -> 9
00000009 -> 9
hello -> hello
00hello -> hello
```