# Adding large numbers in sh file in linux

Tags: linux, shell, unix, sh

I am totally new to shell scripting. Its my first hands on.
I have a script where there are 4 txt files in a path and I am getting the last line from the files which are numbers but when I try to add, it gives "expr:non numeric arguments". My script contains the following script.

```
    one=filename1.txt
    count1=$(tail -1  $one| cut -c 3-)
    echo $count1
    two=filename2.txt
    count2=$(tail -1 $two| cut -c 3-)
    echo $count2
    three=filename3.txt
    count3=$(tail -1 $three| cut -c 3-)
    echo $count3
    four=filename4.txt
    count4=$(tail -1 $four| cut -c 3-)
    echo $count4
    totalCount=`expr $count1 + $count2 + $count3 + $count4`
```

The text files are a large text files where the last line is always a footer for example File1.txt has FT001886157, file2.txt has FT002689634, file3.txt has FT002372958, file4.txt has FT001516254 and my output is

```
    001886157
    002689634
    002372958
    001516254

    expr: non-numeric argument
```

Comment: Use `set -x` to enable tracing so you can see what's actually going on. `echo` isn't suited for debugging -- for example, it doesn't show hidden characters like carriage returns.

Comment: (also, `expr` shouldn't be used for math in modern code -- it was obsoleted for that purpose with native math being part of the POSIX sh standard when it was released in 1991 -- but if expr doesn't like the values you have in your variables, `$(( var1 + var2 ))` probably won't like them either)

Comment: I have also tried $(( var1 + var2 )) but this too not working

Comment: Use `bc` or `awk`. Note also that many tools treat numbers beginning with `0` as octal.

Comment: If you really have numbers too large for the shell to handle natively you'll want to use awk, dc, or bc for math; but it doesn't look like that's your actual problem.

Comment: Once again, I'd want to see a trace log from running your script with `set -x` active.

Comment: I tried removing the leading zeros as well by `c1=$(echo "$count1" | sed 's/^0*//')` then too it tells its not a number

Comment: After using set -xv got to know that `\r` is being added

Comment: As you've presumably gathered from the linked duplicate -- `\r` is otherwise known as CR, from the CRLF sequences used as line separators in DOS/Windows text files. Save content as UNIX text files and they're moot.

Comment: Re leading zeros, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53075017/how-can-i-do-bash-arithmetic-with-variables-that-are-numbers-with-leading-zeroes

Comment: @CharlesDuffy thank you for your set -x answer which gave me the answer to my problem. Successfully removed \r as well by using `c1="${count1/$'\r'/}"`