# Why does the first bash var work but not the other? Trying to increment string ints

Tags: bash

Where it worked...

```
tt=0000005

echo $((tt))

tt=$(($tt+1))

echo $((tt))
```

5

6

Somewhere it stopped working...

```
tt=0056505

echo $((tt))

tt=$(($tt+1))

echo $((tt))
```

23877

23878

Comment: bash interprets numbers that start with "0" as octal, rather than decimal, and 0056505 (octal) = 23877 (decimal). See ["How can I do bash arithmetic with variables that are numbers with leading zeroes?"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53075017/how-can-i-do-bash-arithmetic-with-variables-that-are-numbers-with-leading-zeroes) and ["How can I increment a number in a while-loop while preserving leading zeroes (BASH < V4)"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21592667/how-can-i-increment-a-number-in-a-while-loop-while-preserving-leading-zeroes-ba).

Comment: BTW, for incrementing the variable, a simpler way to write it is `((tt++))`.

Comment: @user1934428 `((tt++))` won't work if the initial value of `tt` is, for instance, `08`.

Comment: @MNejatAydin: Because `08` is not a number, as explained by Gordon Davisson in his comment above. If you initialize it to `8`, it works. BTW, if you initialize  the variable to something like `foobar`, it wouldn't work either.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to trim the leading zeros first

```
$ tt=0056505
$ tt=$(echo $tt | sed 's/^[0]*//g')
$ echo $((tt))
56505
$ tt=$(($tt+1))
$ echo $((tt))
56506
```

Comment: You can also say `tt=$(( 10#$tt + 1 ))` to tell bash to interpret `$tt` as a decimal number.

Comment: That could be useful. Thx.

Comment: Creating a subshell and calling an external program to trim leading `0`s from a shell variable is superfluous. Trimming could be done via shell parameter expansions: `tt=${tt#"${tt%%[^0]*}"}` (instead of `tt=$(echo $tt | sed 's/^[0]*//g')`). Or, in bash, `tt=${tt##+(0)}` after setting the `extglob` shell option by `shopt -s extglob`.